# How to write a wrapper for std::array's list initialization constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

I’m writing a wrapper that, for the purpose of this question, does nothing but wraps a SequenceContainer ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer ) and reproduces all functionality of the SequenceContainer concept the wrapped container offers.

My attempt to write such a wrapper looks like this:

```
template<class Container>
class SequenceContainerWrapper
{
  Container cont;
public:
  using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
  using reference = typename Container::reference;
  using size_type = typename Container::size_type;
  SequenceContainerWrapper(initializer_list<value_type> init) : cont(init) {}
  reference operator[] (size_type n) {return cont[n];}
  // lots of other code that does nothing but wrapping
};
```

And yes – I can use it, for example, with `std::vector`. The below code compiles and works as expected ( http://ideone.com/sYeIeJ ):

```
int main()
{
    SequenceContainerWrapper<vector<int>> vec({1,2,3,4});
    cout << vec[2] << '\n';
}
```

However, this constructor won’t work with `std::array`. This snippet does not compile ( http://ideone.com/5nZhar ):

```
int main()
{
    SequenceContainerWrapper<array<int, 4>> arr({1,2,3,4});
    cout << arr[2] << '\n';
}
```

This is because ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer#cite_note-1 ):

> std::array supports assignment from a braced-init-list, but not from an std::initializer_list

So how can I reproduce in my wrapper the possibility to initialize an `std::array` with a braced-init-list **without sacrificing the genericness of my wrapper and introducing solutions that will cripple the wrapper’s compatibility with e.g. `std::vector`?**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
SequenceContainerWrapper(initializer_list<value_type> init) : cont(init) {}
```

you could use:

```
SequenceContainerWrapper(Container init) : cont(std::move(init)) {}
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/MzRQGC.

Comment: Thank you. But, outta simple curiosity: If a copy constructor is everything you need and will also cover initializer list initialization, then why does `std::vector` provide both constructors? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector We have both `vector( const vector& other );` and `vector( std::initializer_list<T> init );` there. Wouldn’t `vector( const vector& other );` suffice?

Comment: My thinking is, that with your excellent solution, there will be one constructor overload of `std::vector` I will not explicitly wrap; so, assuming that the standard library doesn’t provide redundant functions, there will have to be at least one use case of `std::vector` I will fail to cover…

Comment: @gaazkam, if `std::vector` did not provide `vector( std::initializer_list<T> init )`, you won't be able to use a `std::initializer_list` to construct a temporary `std::vector` in the call to construct a `SequenceContainerWrapper`.

Comment: So… there still be one use case of `std::vector` I won’t cover: `SequenceContainerWrapper<SequenceContainerWrapper<std::vector<int>>> vec2({1,2,3,4});` http://ideone.com/Kv5YtM This is unfortunately an important use-case, since I do nest these wrappers, each alternating the container’s behavior slightly, to achieve the desired outcome with the correct chain of slightly different wrappers.

Comment: With the `SequenceContainerWrapper(initializer_list<value_type> init) : cont(init) {}` I can nest these wrappers http://ideone.com/EKywvb , however unfortunately this ofc breaks `std::array`... Dang.

Comment: @gaazkam, Valid points. I am not sure what would work for all of your use cases.

Comment: Why `const&`?  That seems premature pessimization.

Comment: @Yakk, if you are hinting at a better solution, I am not sure what it is. Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @rsahu drop the `const&` and `std::move`?

Comment: @Yakk, if I change `Container const& init` to `Container&& init`, I am not able to use `std::vector<int> v({1,2,3,4});
   SequenceContainerWrapper<std::vector<int>> vec(v);`. I am forced to use `std::vector<int> v({1,2,3,4});
   SequenceContainerWrapper<std::vector<int>> vec(std::move(v));`. I am not sure whether that is better.

Comment: @rsahu I did not say `&&`.  Just take by value.

Comment: @Yakk, Thanks for being patient. I am still learning the ways of move semantics.