# How to pass a braced-init-list to `std::array`’s constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constructor, list-initialization

Is it possible to pass the exact braced-init-list to `std::array`’s constructor? This might be necessary since `std::array` does not support initializer list assignment.

Trying to adapt the accepted answer of this question: [How to construct std::array object with initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893700/how-to-construct-stdarray-object-with-initializer-list) (answer’s shortened link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894191/4385532 ) to my problem, I came up with the following “solution” to the problem of passing a braced-init-list to the constructor of `std::array`:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N> struct ArrayWrapper
{
    std::array<T,N> arr;
    ArrayWrapper(T &&... init) : arr{{std::forward<T>(init)...}} {}
}
```

I was hoping that this would allow the following syntax:

```
int main()
{
  ArrayWrapper<int, 4> aw{{1,2,3,4}};
  std::cout << aw.arr[2] << '\n';
}
```

However, I failed. This won’t compile: http://ideone.com/VJVU1X

I’m not sure what is my error. I hoped that this line

```
ArrayWrapper(T &&... init) : arr{{std::forward<T>(init)...}} {}
```

would catch the exact elements of the braced-init-list passed to `ArrayWrapper`’s constructor, and forward them to the constructor of `std::array`.

What do I fail to understand?

Comment: `T &&... init` is a pack expansion that does not contain a pack, so it won't work.

Comment: `std::array` is an aggregate – it doesn't _have_ a constructor, and I'm not sure what documentation led you to believe that it would. "*This might be necessary since `std::array` does not support initializer list assignment.*" So? I.e., why do you perceive this to be a problem?

Comment: Is the end-goal here to support specifically this syntax: `ArrayWrapper<int, 4> aw({1,2,3,4});`? Is `ArrayWrapper<int, 4> aw(1,2,3,4);` acceptable? How about `ArrayWrapper<int, 4> aw({{1,2,3,4}});`? This smells strongly like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166663)...

Comment: @ildjarn I’m attempting to write a wrapper that will support every syntax `std::array` supports. As per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer#cite_note-1 `std::array` must support braced-init-list assignment, that is this syntax: `std::array<int, 4> arr({1,2,3,4});`. Since `std::array` supports this syntax, I want my wrapper to support this syntax as well.

Comment: @ildjarn Although strictly speaking you are right, this question is about my failed attempt to solve my problem I stated in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599052/how-to-write-a-wrapper-for-stdarrays-list-initialization-constructor

Comment: @ildjarn I’m sorry. In that case, I’ve edited my question accordingly. I hope the syntax is now correct.

Comment: Per your edit, a constructor like `ArrayWrapper(T const(&a)[N]) { std::copy(a, a+N, arr.data()); }` [would allow such syntax](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72d743b79b8d0d03), but I've no idea if it actually has the semantics you want...